# Our cat began hissing at my boyfriend after 6 months

Tags: cats, training

My boyfriend and I adopted a kitten who was 6weeks old. Dixie (the kitten) has always been lovey and sweet to both of us. She was fixed about a month ago and for the last 2 weeks she hisses at my boyfriend and he can not even go near her let alone touch her. There has not been any traumatic event to cause this either. Dixie is still lovey to me but if my boyfriend comes near her she hisses and runs away. If I am not home she will stay hidden.

I have tried to hold her and be near when he tries to pet me but no luck. We have tried food but she will not accept any food or treats he gives her. I just don’t know what to do because he loves her very much and just doesn’t know what to do.He never had a problem petting her anywhere. She loves attention. She runs away when he is in any position But I’ve tried to have him sit, or lay down also with no luck. I’ve tried bringing the cat over to him when he is asleep in bed and she won’t stay unless she knows he is asleep. He has tried the “reassurance “ look at her. I e told him to try the stare with head down and long slow blink.

Comment: How does your boyfriend act around the cat? Does he go to her and try touching her? Does he look her in the eyes? When he could still pet her, where on her body did he pet her? (head, tummy, along the back?)